# How to make dd fail if it invalid skip value is specified?

Tags: dd, error-handling

When I invoke `dd` with an invalid value for `skip` it prints an error message and does nothing, but doesn't return with a value different from `0`, e.g.

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir xy
$ cd xy
$ truncate -s 2M test.img
$ dd if=test.img of=test-2.img skip=3M
dd: 'test.img': cannot skip to specified offset
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0,000141862 s, 0,0 kB/s
$ echo $?
0
```

This behavior is annoying when `dd` is used in scripts and I'd like to avoid process communication or output parsing different from the well established way of relying to return codes. How to make `dd` appropriate ones?

Answer (score 1):

you can divide by zero.

```
G=$(($((M=$((K=1024))*$K))*$K))
IF=./source_file SKIP=$((3*$M))
dd "if=$IF" "skip=$(($SKIP/($SKIP<$(wc -c <"$IF"))))"
```

That either evaluates to `"$SKIP/1"` or `"$SKIP/0"`. In truth, it isnt `dd` that returns false, but the shell - which does mean that `dd` is never even invoked, but `wc` is of course. It might also be worth running in a subshell because a non-interactive shell will likely exit otherwise.

This is also a basic `bs=1` example - you'd likely have to factor by block-size in most cases or use GNU's *skip-bytes* flag.